# disable shutdown and reboot commands in sudoers file for normal users not working

Tags: centos, sudo, shutdown

I have added the following lines in order to prevent normal users from `soporte` group to shutdown system:

```
cmnd_Alias     SHUTDOWN = /sbin/shutdown,/sbin/reboot,/sbin/halt,/sbin/poweroff
# User privilege specification
gponce   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL, !SHUTDOWN
# Prevent members of group soporte to execute shutdown command
%soporte  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL,  !SHUTDOWN
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In CentOS7 and up, you'd also need to restrict `systemctl halt` and friends, and `sudo bash -c poweroff` etc etc. I hope this is not supposed to be more than a safeguard against accidents.

Comment: You did not tell us what happened when you tried it.

Comment: @ jeff. thanks for your suggestion. Well, even though I have configured in sudoers, all normal users can shutdown system anytime.

Answer (score 2):

Using a blacklist for sudo is a futile effort. If you don't want users to be able to shut down the system, then you need to give them a whitelist of approved commands, rather than trying to block all of the possible commands and sequences of commands that will result in a shutdown, of which there's **a lot** more than you think.

Comment: I am changing the approach based in your recommendation. I am changing chmod for /sbin/shutdown and for poweroff, halt and reboot. thanks

Comment: @GonzaloPonce That doesn't work either, since they could just use sudo to chmod then back, or just create their own program that does the same thing (there's nothing magical about /sbin/shutdown).